# How to do source envvars before running apache

Tags: python, django, apache

Is there a way to do `source credentials` before running a django project from apache? My file looks like:

```
export DB_USERNAME=root
export DB_HOST=xx.yy.ss.dd
```

Or, do I have to put everything in my wsgi.py file?

Comment: Are you trying to modify the settings based on the environment?

Comment: Apache is started by `apachectl` which looks into `.../bin/envvars`.  This would apply the configurations to Apache at start.  If this is not acceptable (i.e. values can change for each django project), then the .py file is the only option IMHO.